# How to access Mediapipe Hand Landmarks for Android (Java)

Tags: android, computer-vision, mediapipe

How can the landmarks for hands be accessed in the Android version of MediaPipe? (Java)

I'd like to access the joints' positions in space.

A similar project that someone else has done in Python is available.
https://github.com/GasbaouiMohammedAlAmin/Finger-Counter-using-Hand-Tracking-And-Open-cv
The landmarks seem to be from the "solutions" part of the library.

I have a sample of code that works for Android, but it seems that all the processing is done without ever giving the landmarks to the Java file. https://github.com/jiuqiant/mediapipe_multi_hands_tracking_aar_example Is the base code of my project.

From that file, `getMultiHandLandmarksDebugString` takes in NormalizedLandmarkList, but how can those landmarks be accessed normally in the program?

```
import com.google.mediapipe.formats.proto.LandmarkProto.NormalizedLandmark;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the result is the object of HandsResults

To get the landmark position of each points i have used a list of normalizedlandmark type

```
List<NormalizedLandmark> ll = result.multiHandLandmarks().get(0).getLandmarkList();
```

The list size will be 21 to access those i have created a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < ll.size(); i++)
```

For getting x, y and z of each of 21 landmarks

```
int x = (int) (ll.get(i).getX() * 1280);
```

Multiplied by 1280 texture width to get the pixel value

Here is the sample code u can check it out for more reference follow this [link](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/63e679d99ca45b30514a9d84c9351a2d77bb9ba0/mediapipe/examples/android/solutions/hands/src/main/java/com/google/mediapipe/examples/hands/MainActivity.java#L339)

```
List<NormalizedLandmark> ll = result.multiHandLandmarks().get(0).getLandmarkList();
        Log.d("check", String.valueOf(ll.get(0).getX()));
        for (int i = 0; i < ll.size(); i++) {

            int x = (int) (ll.get(i).getX() * 1280);
            int y = (int) (ll.get(i).getY() * 720);
//            Log.d("chec1", String.valueOf(i)+" "+String.valueOf(x)+" "+String.valueOf(y));
            for (int tip : finger_tips) {
                Log.d("chec1", String.valueOf(tip) + " " + String.valueOf((int) (ll.get(tip).getX() * 1280)) + " " + String.valueOf((int) (ll.get(tip).getY() * 720)));
                if ((ll.get(tip).getX() * 1280) < (ll.get(tip - 3).getX() * 1280)) {
                    finger_fold_status.add(false);
                } else {
                    finger_fold_status.add(true);
                }
            }
            int r = (int) (ll.get(thumb_tip-1).getY()*1280);
            if(((int)ll.get(thumb_tip).getY()*1280)<r && r< (ll.get(thumb_tip-2).getY()*1280)){
                if(finger_fold_status.contains(true)){
                    Log.d("res","LIke");
                    is = true;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tv.setText(R.string.like);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }if(((int)ll.get(thumb_tip).getY()*1280)>r && r>(ll.get(thumb_tip-2).getY()*1280)){
                if(finger_fold_status.contains(true)){
                    Log.d("res1","DisLIke");
                    is = false;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tv.setText(R.string.dislike);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            Log.d("stat", String.valueOf(finger_fold_status));
        }
```